# Script Linux csh to create a log

Tags: linux, logging

I have a process that starts every day and I'd like to create a log that says me when is completed.

I'm a newbie on Linux, I haven't programmed before, but I've tried to write this code

```
#!/bin/csh
set today=`date '+%Y%m%d'`
set LOG_DIR=${SL_ROOT_FOLDER}/log/cod_flow_extractor
set LOG_FILE=settlement_report_procedure
set LOG_FILE=${LOG_DIR}/${LOG_FILE}.log_$_"$today.log"
echo "$LOG_FILE"
#eval  $LOG_FILE
#exec >> $LOG_FILE 2>&1
#exec  $LOG_FILE
alias log
echo "currDate=`date +%Y%m%d.%H:%M:%S`"
```

When I executed it, I haven't got a log.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's no statement writing to the log file, what would you like to log?

Comment: @orhtej2 I'd like to log the date (YYYY-dd-mm hh-mm-sec) when the process is finished

Comment: Must read: [csh programming considered harmful](https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html). Use a better shell, e.g. [zsh](http://zsh.org/)

Comment: You could be interested in [logger(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html). It uses [syslog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) and [openlog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/openlog.3.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just redirect the output of the last `echo` statement:

```
#!/bin/csh
set today=`date '+%Y%m%d'`
# $SL_ROOT_FOLDER is defined elsewhere
set LOG_DIR=${SL_ROOT_FOLDER}/log/cod_flow_extractor
set LOG_FILE=settlement_report_procedure
# notice I removed excess '_$'
set LOG_FILE=${LOG_DIR}/${LOG_FILE}."$today.log"
# let's see if its a correct path
echo "$LOG_FILE"
echo "currDate=`date +%Y%m%d.%H:%M:%S`" > $LOG_FILE
```